# Getting a Column on the next Row on excel with Macro

Tags: vba, excel

i need as the title says to put the data from a column onto the next row.
After a lot of research i learned that it can be done using macros and this is where i need your help.

Example of what i need to do:

What i mean is that i have an excel doc with 4 columns

```
   A      B       C        D
1  Data1   Data2  Data3   Data4
2  Data5   Data6  Data7   Data8
```

I want every D column data to go to the next line like this.

```
   A      B       C       
1  Data1   Data2  Data3   
2  Data4   // First Data of D column on below line moved on line 2
3  Data5   Data6  Data7 
4  Data8  // Second Data of D column on below line moved on line 4.
```

So i recorded a macro of adding a line on "2" and cuttin-paste the first D on the new 2. The code is this:

```
Sub Data1()
'
' Data1 Macro
'
' 
'
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1:D1").Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Insert , CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 3).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Cut
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, -3).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

Result:

[image: https://s32.postimg.org/xqofxu1lh/Work1.png]

The thing is that with a lot of data that needs to be run a lot of times so a loop is really needed here.

Tried using a loop but iam stack here and there is where i need your help

Thats how far iam but it doesnt work now as it should.

```
Dim x As Integer

Sub Data1()
'
' Data1 Macro
'
' 
'
    x = 1


    Do While x <= 20 ' that i will change as how many columns i have.
        ActiveCell.Offset(x, 0).Range("A1:D1").Select
        Selection.EntireRow.Insert , CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        ActiveCell.Offset(x - 2, x + 2).Range("A1").Select
        Selection.Cut
        ActiveCell.Offset(x, x - 4).Range("A1").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste

        x = x + 2 ' if it starts from cell no1 and we have a blank to fill with Data4 or Data8 of D row then we need x+2 i believe and not x+1.
    Loop
End Sub
```

Result with lots of data and 2nd modified (not working) code:

[image: https://s31.postimg.org/c1ffzj4nv/Notwork.png]

thanks in advance.

Comment: "_but it doesnt work now as it should_" can you explain more? what is the output.

Comment: With the first recorded macro i get this. https://s32.postimg.org/xqofxu1lh/Work1.png
With the second and adding more data in the array i get this.
https://s31.postimg.org/c1ffzj4nv/Notwork.png
from this https://s32.postimg.org/5d0qlsvkl/sample.png

Comment: you should edit your question to add these images in instead of keeping them in comments

Comment: done with the 2 links only as i dont have rep but ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this would be a simple loop through all of the data in D, though the parameters of the loop are complicated by the addition of rows as the loop runs.  This is solved by using a do while loop and incrementing the check condition along with the counter

```
Sub ConvertColDtoRow()
'Note that this code is written specifically for column D, but it can be adjusted as needed by changing the column specified

Dim Count As Long, LastRow As Long
Count = 1
LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
Do While Count <= LastRow
    If Not IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.Cells(Count,4)) Then
        Range(Cells(Count,4).Address).Offset(1,0).EntireRow.Insert
        Cells(Count + 1,1).Value = Cells(Count,4).Value
        Cells(Count,4).Value = ""
        Count = Count + 2
        LastRow = LastRow + 1
    Else
        Count = Count + 1
    End If
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much @RGA. Your are saving a lot of time for me here.

Comment: If you can edit Count < LastRow to Count <= LastRow , it changes last row too with =.

Comment: @foutzos That's exactly what stackoverflow is for.  You took the time to ask a question properly per community guidelines, so I am happy to take the time to help :)